# 3d / 2.5d game library for iphone and pc

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to make a 2d shooter game with 3d background.

The player and enemies are essentially just quads with textures.

The background will be simple 3d polygons with textures and some fog and light.

Therefore, I don't need a really powerful 3d library.

I tried Unity3D and Torque2D, but I don't like to use their GUI editors. I prefer to work with code.

So, is there a **cross platform (mainly windows and iPhone)** 3d / 2.5d game library, commercial or open source?

I assume it will be only limited to c, c++, and object-c due to apple's new ToS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recall that there is an Ogre3D port to iPhone, but I don't remember its name just now.

Comment: It seems Ogre3D does have limited iphone support. I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 2):

Cocos2D works on [iPhone](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/).

Comment: As far as I know, Cocos2d-iphone only works with iphone. I need something that will be able to run on windows as well

Comment: mac port available - used it first-hand: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/1074

Answer (score 1):

If you just want some simple images you can just use OpenGL ES. I've heard it's quite nice to program with it on iPhone. Also, take a look at [parallax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax). If you want to do 2.5D games I think it's a must.
Good luck